# Display a toast message on dialer screen while making an outgoing call in Android

Tags: android, android-toast

I am developing an Android app and I am blocked at one place. I want to toast a one liner very small text in dialer screen while user dialed a number. This similar thing true-caller app has used. In similar way I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Use ui thread. this will work

```
Classname.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     Public void run(){
         Toast.makeText(classname.this,"WORKING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 });
```